# MSBuild path related issue

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have a library and creating a Nuget for it, the same time
have MSBuild and .targets file defining what to move.

**Build\proj.targets file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExResources Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\staticwebassets\ExFiles\*" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="@(ExResources)" />    
    <DefaultValues Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\staticwebassets\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyResources" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile" >
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Copying resources to consumer app!" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="First up, all resources, except the default config" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="@(ExResources)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ExResources)"
          DestinationFolder="$(MsBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\component_library\" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Now what's left is the default config, which we only write if it doesn't exist yet" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="@(DefaultValues)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DefaultValues)"
          DestinationFolder="$(MsBuildProjectDirectory)\wwwroot\"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**in .csProj file:**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="build\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="build\*.targets" PackagePath="build\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

---

**Have 2 issues with it:**

**First, is when running msbuild getting the below error:**

*(**ExFiles** is located in the root of the library)*

```
proj.targets(46,7): 
error MSB4184: 
The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. 
The path is not of a legal form.
```

Second, This error is not telling which path.
Built using various forms, commands and tools, like:

```
dotnet msbuild "D:\SSS\Proj.csproj" -v:diag -bl
```

tried also MSBuild structured Log Viewer, which didn't show any additional information.

none of the messages in the .targets file being shown in the VS output window.
So, I never saw `"Copying resources to consumer app!"` or the value of `"@(ExResources)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error MSB4184:  The expression
>   "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated.  The
>   path is not of a legal form.

I think you did not provide the whole info in `proj.targets` file and in that file and you certainly use `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName` function to pass a value to a property in `proj.targets` file.

If so, you should use this type:

`<new property>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(Property1)))</new Property>`

**Note**:

From the error message, it can be that the Property1 is not defined in current property. So you should make sure that it is defined before `new Property`.

Also, you would better create this new property under a new **PropertyGroup** and this will avoid some trouble.

So try these in `proj.targets`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Property1>xxx</Property1>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
<new property>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(Property1)))</new Property>
</PropertyGroup>
```

> none of the messages in the .targets file being shown in the VS output
>   window. So, I never saw "Copying resources to consumer app!" or the
>   value of "@(ExResources)"

Did you pack this library and then install it on another project, if so, you should check the build output on the new project rather than `dotnet msbuild "D:\SSS\Proj.csproj" -v:diag`(the library project) and the `proj.targets` will play a role in the new project after you install the library package. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

**Note**: the `build/<package_id>.targets` in the nuget mechanism is automatically imported into a new project that references the nuget package and is used in the new project instead of the current library project.

**In addition**, if you want to see the `props.targets` file in the library project,  you should configure the file into library project manually and make sure that you have  in this `<Import Project="xxxxx\build\props.targets" />` in current `Proj.csproj`, and then your library project can use it.

**And** you can use `dotnet msbuild "D:\SSS\Proj.csproj" -v:diag` to see that.

Hope it could help you and if I misunderstand your issue, please feel free to let us know and provide any detailed info for us to research it.

Comment: Thanks Perry Qian, I marked it as the answer +1, I employed a library, and that was the extra configuration, I thought most of the MSBuild script provided is standalone, and didn't notice GetDirectoryName could be part of that library, please give me 1-2h to read/apply/research a bit on what you provided, will back to you then for extra feedback, questions and more details if needed.

Comment: Was trying to use https://github.com/excubo-ag/Blazor.LazyStyleSheet library, I pasted the .target file of that project into https://hastebin.com/axutokiveg.xml

Comment: Does it clear anything for you? Do you know what could be the best next moves for me to find the issue and debug/handle next issues in a more convenient way?

Comment: And If your project does not explicitly use the package, you simply uninstall it

Comment: My project uses it, talked with it's author, he told those SCSS files can be independant to components. How can I log, debug the path causing that error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213405/discussion-between-kasrak-and-perry-qian-msft).

Comment: Hello, can we continue this today? Have you tried the sample?

Comment: Sure. You can share an onedrive's link. And be careful to hide personal and private information.

Comment: Shared onedrive link at the first day of discussion, now was waiting some days to see if you made any progress or was able to help on it or not, what else you waiting for to be shared? I also watch all the time the chat session: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213405/discussion-between-kasrak-and-perry-qian-msft

Comment: I found that in ScssStructure project, it lose data folder, did you miss such file? And in my test, it did not face the error `The expression "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName('')" cannot be evaluated. ` and got another different error. So since it is another issue, I suggest you can create a new ticket(create an new issue). Besides, I face error `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers, version 3.1.3 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore`. I wonder if you face it too.

Comment: I suspect that it is related to my sdk version on my agent. I will look into the problem as soon as possible.

Comment: Please check the chat if possible, in another hand still I am not able to make the "Messages" work.